# Movie Not Loading

Tags: jquery, flash

Im using a plugin called prettyPhoto. It seems to be wokring except for the video is not loading. I don't have much experience with movies and or flash.

Here is my code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="js/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    autoplay: true, /* Automatically start videos: True/False */
  });
```

and the markup

```
<a href="swf/player.swf?url=http://flyfishinggreyriver.com/NFF.flv?width=792&amp;height=294" rel="prettyPhoto[flash]" title="teaser" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image6','','Images/video_tour2.jpg',1)"><img src="Images/video_tour1.jpg" alt="take a video tour" name="Image6" width="340" height="81" border="0" id="Image6" /></a>
```

here is the page link, (it's the take a video tour link)
http://www.flyfishinggreyriver.com/fly_fishing3.html
thank you!

Comment: thanks for responding. just tried it ... but no dice

Answer (score 0):

Since you're passing the FLV path as a query string parameter, you need to escape it. Works fine with an escaped path.

Comment: so, do you mean just replace the ? with %3F

Comment: I tried that and it makes the player the right size (which is good!) but still no movie...

Comment: http://www.flyfishinggreyriver.com/swf/player.swf?width=792&height=294&url=http%3A%2F%2Fflyfishinggreyriver.com%2FNFF.flv - it works just fine for me when i put it inside `href` attribute via firebug.

Comment: so any clue why its not working here? www.flyfishinggreyriver.com/fly_fishing3.html